# loading external data not working properly with multiple links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When there are multiple links, modal dialog is loaded just as many times as the number of the links.

For example, if there are 3 links with `class="test"`, when first link is clicked, it will load 3 times on top of each.

Anyway to fix it?

```
<a href="/user/login/" class="test">comment #1</a><br>
<a href="/user/signup/" class="test">comment #2</a><br>
<a href="/user/reset_password/" class="test">comment #3</a><br>

  $('a.test').click(function() {
        var url = this.href;
        // show a spinner or something via css
        var dialog = $('<div style="display:none" class="loading"></div>').appendTo('body');
        // open the dialog
        dialog.dialog({
            // add a close listener to prevent adding multiple divs to the document
            close: function(event, ui) {
                // remove div with all data and events
                dialog.remove();
            },
            width: 400,
            modal: true
        });
        // load remote content
        dialog.load(
            url, 
            {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                // remove the loading class
                dialog.removeClass('loading');
            }
        );
        //prevent the browser to follow the link
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('body').append('<div id="newDialog" class="loading"></div>');
        $("#newDialog").dialog({
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $("#newDialog").html("").addClass('loading');
            },
            width: 400,
            modal: true
        });
         $('a.test').click(function() {
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#newDialog").load(
                url, 
                {},
                function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $("#newDialog").removeClass('loading').dialog("open");
                }
            );
            return false;
        });  
    });
</script>
```

It reduces the number of times you have to initiate $.dialog() which is extremely costly.

Also it gets rid of the multiple dialogs on the same click.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. it works fine with the first link but it does not open others.

Comment: Sorry, change this: `var url = this.href;` to this `var url = $(this).attr("href");`. Copy/Paste, gets me every time...

Comment: Also I would change this `$("#newDialog").html("");` to this `$("#newDialog").html("").addClass('loading');` in the dialog close event. Just noticed it...